# Hendershot generator w/unpolorized capacitors

Tags: generator

does the Hendershot fueless generator work?

Comment: It works better if you add fuel.

Comment: Just google for: `site:hendershotgenerator.com filetype:pdf` and you'll find all the PDF's they are trying to sell you from that site.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Hendershot Generator is a scam, like any other perpetual motion machine, or other means of obtaining energy from nothing.

Lester Hendershot, the purported "inventor" of the device, conveniently did not leave any working design diagrams in his papers. Subsequently his son Mark Hendershot tried for several years to create a working implementation of the so-called "free energy generator", before finally giving up.

In any case, it is a basic tenet of Physics that neither matter nor energy can be created - they can be collected (solar), transduced or transformed, even between forms, but for any output there must be an input.

Were a machine like the Hendershot Generator at all feasible, the world's energy crisis would end, and if nothing else, the nations spending immense amounts of foreign exchange for petroleum imports would force such a device to mass production, to eliminate the economic hegemony of the oil-producing nations.

This question probably belongs better to the [Skeptics StackExchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a vast number of "free power" or "over unity" systems being promoted.

Those who "believe in them" do so with religious zeal and no rational argument will sway them from their beliefs in the system.

Accordingly there are a large number of "conmen" who prey on the true believers.
There are also those who genuinely believe in their systems, regardless of the complete lack of hard measurement data which clearly demonstrates their success.

The "hallmarks" of such systems may include

- use of magnets or magnetic fields,

  special demonstrations or conditions on how or when or to who demonstrations will be shown,

  systems that work for a small group but can never be replicated by others.

  References without concise meaningful explanations to gravity, crystals, over-unity, golden ratio, any ratio, oxygen free copper. ...

Hendershot died in 1961 - 52 years ago. 
It's long long long overdue for his machine to make its public debut and save the world.

His 'generator' has all the signs of being yet another scam or, at best, deluded dream.  Alas.